# API quando online, retorna: 'Route [login] not defined'

Tags: laravel

Estou testando uma *API* que estou desenvolvendo, em *localhost* consigo fazer uma determinada requisição e ela me retorna tudo 'ok'. Ao fazer o mesmo teste em um servidor, ela está retornando um '*Route [login] not defined.*' 
Sendo que não estou associando nenhum *middleware* de autenticação a minha *API* e nem associando no construtor do meu *controller*.

```
public function getListById($id)
{
    $user = DB::table('dbTestes')->where('id', $id)->get();
    return response()->json($user);
}


//Rota API:

Route::get('/ponto/edit/{id}', 'PontoController@getListById');
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Estou acessando o mesmo banco de dados.

Comment: Onde você está dizendo o URL do acesso?

Comment: meudominio.com/api/...

Comment: No seu router, vc especificou que o middleware é api? O laravel tbm tem um arquivo específico pra criar rotas de api, diferente de quando vc usa o routes web, além disso, se por algum motivo vc estiver numa rota protegida o laravel está te redirecionando pra rota de login, que neste caso não existe

Comment: Não, não está definido nenhum middleware em nas rotas da API.